# Does python 2.7 support an ActiveX Interface?

Tags: python-2.7, activex, add-in, enterprise-architect

I am developing an Addin to Enterprise Architect. But before that i need to know if python 2.7 supports an ActiveX Interface?.i searched a lot but there is no direct answer. Any help or code sample is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [pywin32 library](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/).
After you import the win32com part, the following script accesses the EA interface:

```
 App = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("EA.App")
 EA = App.Repository

 if not EA.OpenFile("PATHTOYOUR.eap"):
     print ("load failed")

 for package in EA.Models:
     print(package.Name);

 Project = EA.GetProjectInterface()
 Project.Exit()
```

I don't know how you develop an addin for EA, but that should you get started.